# Is there a google API to read cached content?

Tags: caching, google-api, web-scraping, google-search, google-search-api

I know you can go to http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://example.com/ to view Google's cache of any URL, but do they provide an API to hit thousands of these and pay for access?

I don't want to just make HTTP GETs to these URLs too fast and get my IP addresses banned or upset Google.

Just wondering if they offer a way to pay and do this through official channels like they do with their search API.

Answer (score 4):

Google doesn't seem to have an [API](https://developers.google.co/products/) to access the cached results:

There are some attempts to scrape it and wrap it in APIs, such as this [perl module](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/WWW-Cache-Google-0.04/lib/WWW/Cache/Google.pm)

Other than that the Wayback Machine has an [API](http://archive.org/help/wayback_api.php), of cached versions of sites. Perhaps that will do?

Answer (score -1):

Currently there's no tool that I've found that does it. You'd have to create your own script to individually cache a certain number of pages. To avoid Google blocking you, I suggest capping the number of urls scraped. Not ideal, but running a script 10 times is better than looking at 1000 cached urls individually. :/

If you want to see if anything you edit on your site would effect your potential rankings in Google, I'd check out SEORadar.com, they'll do that for you.