# How to access content indexed by google when domain is expired or site not working

Tags: javascript, php, google-search

So, I do a google search of, for example enaidurabigstep, and I can see search results for the website enaidurabigstep.com. Sometimes,I am not able to access the website by clicking on the results link, maybe because the domain is currently expired or the website is down. My question is, since google has indexed information on this website, is there any way to request google for it?
Maybe programmatically, by using javascript or php?

Comment: Google usually offers you the ability to view a cached version of a result via the little downwards pointing triangle next to it. If that _doesn’t_ show this option for a particular result, then I’d rather doubt they would expose this via an API either.

Comment: Here an older question asking for such an API, but back then at least it seems that did not exist: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010131/is-there-a-google-api-to-read-cached-content