# Google Search Console API - Get HTML from URL?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I would like to know if there's a way using Google Search Console's (or Google Analytics') API to fetch the HTML of a page, given its URL. Seems pretty basic but I haven't been able to find anything myself by googling.

Comment: Can you include a bit more detail on why you can't just perform an HTTP GET on the URL in question from your own environment, as opposed to using Google as a *de facto* proxy?

Comment: @esqew I don't know a ton about this stuff, but there are websites (e.g. linkedin) that authwall you from your own device (thus giving a useless html page), but they don't do so to Google Analytics. So yes, I'm using Google as a sort of proxy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a google API to read cached content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010131/is-there-a-google-api-to-read-cached-content)

Comment: I don't think so - I don't need the result to be cached, it can be a live result - forgive me if I sound like I don't know what I'm talking about, because I don't.